# nginx proxy_pass to https / image-server not working

Tags: nginx, proxy, webserver, nginx-reverse-proxy, proxypass

I'm trying to proxy an image server imagekit.io so that all requests have same domain name.

Have tried multiple configurations in HTTPS nginx server (with self-signed certificate) and even in HTTP server.

Let's say the URL is https://ik.imagekit.io/hj8sm3kk7/brochures/92/1579/suzuki-gsx-r150-615123.pdf

With the below configuration, I'm trying to hit http://localhost.com:8800/brochures/92/1579/suzuki-gsx-r150-615123.pdf

```
server {
        listen       8800;
        server_name  localhost.com;

        location /brochures {   
            proxy_ignore_headers Set-Cookie;
           proxy_set_header Host ik.imagekit.io;                       
           # proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
           # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           proxy_set_header Pragma no-cache;
           proxy_set_header Accept $http_accept;
           proxy_set_header User-Agent $http_user_agent;
            proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding $http_accept_encoding;
            proxy_set_header Accept-Language $http_accept_language;
            proxy_set_header sec-fetch-mode navigate;
            proxy_set_header sec-fetch-site cross-site;
            proxy_set_header sec-fetch-user ?1;
            proxy_set_header :authority ik.imagekit.io;
            proxy_set_header :method GET;
            proxy_set_header :path $path;
            proxy_set_header :scheme https;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade-Insecure-Requests 1;

           proxy_pass https://ik.imagekit.io/hj8sm3kk7/brochures;
        }
}
```

This however works:

http://localhost.com:8800/financial-advisor/mfs-investment-management-review opens the same page as https://smartasset.com/financial-advisor/mfs-investment-management-review

```
location /financial-advisor {                        
           proxy_ignore_headers Set-Cookie;
           proxy_set_header     Host          $host;                       
           proxy_set_header     X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header     X-Forwarded-For         $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           proxy_pass https://smartasset.com;
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

The real issue turned out to be an SSL problem with `ik.imagekit.io`, using `http://` instead of `https://` in the `proxy_pass` value helps.

---

Original (and wrong) answer I've given:

---

The first example requires a manipulation of the URL path. Consider a similar approach:

```
location ~ ^/(brochures/.*) {
  # all the previous config you used should be added here
  proxy_pass  https://ik.imagekit.io/hj8sm3kk7/$1;
}
```

This will proxy the request to the proper URL path, which changes from the original request. `$1` is the part of the request URL path that matches the first brackets `(...)`.

Comment: Doesn't work.

Also tried below config and the url < http://localhost.com:8800/hj8sm3kk7/brochures/92/1579/suzuki-gsx-r150-615123.pdf>
```location /hj8sm3kk7 {   
            # all other config;
            proxy_pass https://ik.imagekit.io;
        }```
That didn't work either. There's some other problem I guess.

Comment: Hmmm consider enabling logging to see the exact proxied URL? Add `$proxy_host` and `$upstream_addr` to the access_log and see what happens to your request.

Comment: Somehow both ```$proxy_host``` and ```$upstream_addr``` are giving ```-```. Used this log format ```log_format upstreamlog '[$time_local] $remote_addr - $remote_user - $server_name  to: "$upstream_addr": "$request" "$request_method $scheme://$proxy_host$request_uri $server_protocol"';``` The log I got was ```[27/Oct/2019:01:27:06 +0530] 127.0.0.1 - - - localhost.com  to: "-": "GET /brochures/92/1579/suzuki-gsx-r150-615123.pdf HTTP/1.1" "GET http://-/brochures/92/1579/suzuki-gsx-r150-615123.pdf HTTP/1.1"``` This log is with the location config you suggested.

Comment: Seems like the rule doesn't catch. Try adding a `~` so that you have `location ~ ^/hj8sm3kk7`, without it only `http://localhost/hj8sm3kk7` is proxied. NOPE the above is incorrect, forget I said so.

Comment: Tried with ```location ~ ^/hj8sm3kk7 { #other config;  proxy_pass  https://ik.imagekit.io; }``` and url <http://localhost.com:8800/hj8sm3kk7/brochures/92/1579/suzuki-gsx-r150-615123.pdf>. Still the same error :(

Comment: I found the issue :) When proxying `https://ik.imagekit.io`, I see SSL errors. Adjust `https` to `http` to resolve?

Comment: You're a genius, thank you! It does work now. I spent 2 days trying to figure this out. Anyway, is there some response header which suggested they don't serve SSL properly?

Comment: No genius, just poking at stuff randomly! Didn't inspect headers, only saw SSL errors in error_log prior to the expected access_log. Glad to have helped, will adjust original answer!